# OPENCART search by model in featured module

Tags: opencart, opencart-module

in opencart when edit my featured module, and add new product, my search is by name, and not by model...

it is possible search by product model?? and not by name

this happens in all modules that need to add a product

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do much more just edit below file only:

```
\opt\lampp\htdocs\opencart\admin\view\template\module\featured.tpl
```

on Line no.121

```
url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
```

You need to just

```
url: 'index.php?route=catalog/product/autocomplete&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&filter_model=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
```

you need to filter_model as parameter which you will be type